# Exception occurred calling method NotesDatabase.getDocumentByUNID(null) null

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I don't understand why I'm getting the above mentioned error with following code :

```
value1 = sessionScope.get("selectedPicture");
if (value1 != "empty"){
    var db:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(database.getServer(), "product\\picture.nsf");
    if (db != null) {
        var IDtoChange = toString("7D59468E241AC271C1257D5000417E46") ;
        if (IDtoChange = null){
           return
        }
        try {
             doc = db.getDocumentByUNID(IDtoChange);
             doc.replaceItemValue( 'picWeb', "true" );
             doc.save( true, false );
             sessionScope.put("selectedUnid","");
        } catch(e) {
             sessionScope.put("error",(e.toString()));
             context.redirectToPage("errorPage.xsp");
       }
   }
}
```

When I replace the line doc = db.getDocumentByUNID(IDtoChange); with doc = db.getDocumentByUNID("7D59468E241AC271C1257D5000417E46"); everything works fine

What is wrong ? (in my real code the id isn't hard coded of course)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should line six be `if (IDtoChange == null){` instead of `if (IDtoChange = null){`.  The single `=` looks to be assigning the value instead of comparing which is `==`

Comment: Rob, when I change the code as per your suggestion I get another error message : Exception occurred calling method NotesDatabase.getDocumentByUNID(string) null

Comment: Try changing `var IDtoChange = toString("7D59468E241AC271C1257D5000417E46") ;` to `var IDtoChange = "7D59468E241AC271C1257D5000417E46" ;`

Comment: Rob, it works this way. Strange, I thought it had to be a string, so that's why I had put "toString"